# Thymeleaf control check box in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have a form which has a check box.After submitting the form i want to control if user checked the box.

Here is my code sample:

```
<form action="DoLogin" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <h3>Giriş</h3>
    <label><span>Kullanıcı:</span></label> <input type="text" placeholder="E-posta adresinizi Giriniz" class="round" name="userName" id="userName" required="true" ></input>
    <label><span>Parola:</span></label> <input type="text" placeholder="Parolanızı Giriniz...." name="password" id="password" required="true" ></input> 
    <label>Giriş Yaparak <span href="#" style="color: red;">Kullanıcı Sözleşmesini</span> Kabul Ediyorum...</label> <input id="userAgreement" type="checkbox" th:checked="${true}"></input>
    <label for="checkbox1" class="round" th:checked="${true}"  id="userAgreement" >Beni Hatırla</label> 
    <a href="#" class="button login round" onclick="login();return false">Giriş</a>
</form>
```

Here is my js code:

```
function login(){

    var control=true;

    userName =  $('#userName').val(),
    password =  $('#password').val(),
    userAgree = $('#userAgreement').checked`enter code here`

    if(userName.length == 0 ) {

        alert('Lütfen e-posta adresini giriniz.')

        return false;

    }else if( password.length == 0 ){

        alert('Lütfen parolanızı giriniz.')

        return false;

    }else if( userAgree == false ){

        alert('Lütfen kullanıcı sözleşmesini okudum bölümünü işaretleyiniz.')

        return false;
    }


    $('#loginForm').submit();

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

userAgree == false means !$("#userAgreement").is(":checked")

Answer (score 1):

```
//override the form submit function that will return false when check box is not checked and
// will not submit the form

$("form").submit(function(){
if(!$("#userAgreement").is(":checked"))
{
alert("Please check the agreement");
return false;
}

});
// add above code in your js

function login(){

    var control=true;

    userName =  $('#userName').val(),
    password =  $('#password').val(),
    userAgree = $('#userAgreement').checked`enter code here`

    if(userName.length == 0 ) {

        alert('Lütfen e-posta adresini giriniz.')

        return false;

    }else if( password.length == 0 ){

        alert('Lütfen parolanızı giriniz.')

        return false;

    }else if( userAgree == false ){

        alert('Lütfen kullanıcı sözleşmesini okudum bölümünü işaretleyiniz.')

        return false;
    }


    $('#loginForm').submit();

};
```